# Rcpp find unique character vectors

Tags: rcpp

I am learning Rcpp from Hadley Wickham's Advance R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html.

There is one exercise to implement R function unique() in Rcpp using an unordered_set (challenge: do it in one line!). The solution finds the unique numbers in a numeric vector. I am trying to find the unique characters in a character vector using the second code chunk, which produces an error. Any idea on how to achieve this simple function manually ? Thanks!

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
    std::unordered_set<double> uniqueCC(NumericVector x) {
      return std::unordered_set<double>(x.begin(), x.end());
    }
    
    
    
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    std::unordered_set<String> uniqueCC(CharacterVector x) {
      return std::unordered_set<String>(x.begin(), x.end());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For object types not in the STL library you need to define your own hash function. `String` (capital S) is an Rcpp object.

The easiest way to do this is to use Rcpp's ability to convert to common STL objects.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::unordered_set<std::string> uniqueCC(CharacterVector x) {
  auto xv = Rcpp::as<std::vector<std::string>>(x);
  return std::unordered_set<std::string>(xv.begin(), xv.end());
}

> x <- sample(letters, 1000, replace=T)
> uniqueCC(x)
 [1] "r" "o" "c" "n" "f" "s" "y" "l" "i" "j" "m" "v" "t" "p" "u" "x" "w" "k" "g" "a" "d" "q" "z" "b" "h" "e"
```

Alternatively, you can take in a STL string vector and Rcpp magic will do the rest:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::unordered_set<std::string> uniqueCC(const std::vector<std::string> & x) {
  return std::unordered_set<std::string>(x.begin(), x.end());
}
```